# Creating multiple event triggers inside one trigger postgres

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I am new to postgres. I want to create a trigger on insert/updated/delete event on a table. I have seen examples showing, trigger created for each event. I was wondering if i can create one trigger for all events together and i know kind of event inside the trigger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.

If you write your trigger in PL/pgSQL, you will have the special variable `TG_OP` defined. The values are `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` or `TRUNCATE`, based on what operation caused the trigger to run.

See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-DML-TRIGGER) for details.